# sort object by content type

Tags: javascript, object

How do I sort object by content type?

```
const myObject = {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "my object",
    "content": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "description": "my description",
    "anotherArray": [11, 22, 33],
    "contentObject": {
        "id": 56,
        "name": "content object"
    }
}
```

I would like the sorting order to be:

1. numeric values
2. strings
3. arrays
4. objects
5. anything else

I found this, [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value), but I am looking for sorting by content type, not content value.

So far I've got...

```
const getDefaultTypeValue = (value) => {

    const val = value;
    let newVal = null;

    const isString =    (value) => (typeof value === 'string' || value instanceof String);
    const isNumber =    (value) => (typeof value === 'number' && isFinite(value));
    const isArray =     (value) => (Array.isArray(value));
    const isFunction =  (value) => (typeof value === 'function');
    const isNull =      (value) => (value === null);
    const isUndefined = (value) => (typeof value === 'undefined');
    const isBoolean =   (value) => (typeof value === 'boolean');
    const isDate =      (value) => (value instanceof Date);
    const isRegExp =    (value) => (value && typeof value === 'object' && value.constructor === RegExp);
    const isError =     (value) => (value instanceof Error && typeof value.message !== 'undefined');
    const isSymbol =    (value) => (typeof value === 'symbol');

    if (isString(val)) {
        newVal = '';
    } else if (isNumber(val)) {
        newVal = null;
    } else if (isArray(val)) {
        newVal = [];
    } else if (isFunction(val)) {
        newVal = val;
    } else if (isUndefined(val)) {
        newVal = undefined;
    } else if (isBoolean(val)) {
        newVal = false;
    } else if (isDate(val)) {
        newVal = new Date();
    } else if (isRegExp(val)) {
        newVal = '';
    } else if (isError(val)) {
        newVal = null;
    } else if (isSymbol(val)) {
        newVal = null;
    } else if (isNull(val)) {
        newVal = null;
    }

    return newVal;
}
```

But I really can't think of how to implement this.

Expected output:

```
const myObject = {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "my object",
    "description": "my description",
    "content": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "anotherArray": [11, 22, 33],
    "contentObject": {
        "id": 56,
        "name": "content object"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you've tried so far.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: Objects are not ordered.

Comment: "Sorting" an object is not possible, since objects are not guaranteed to be specifically ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ypou8 could rebuild the object by checking the types and use a numerical value (the index) for sorting. Unknown types are sorted to the end of the array for rebuilding the object.

```js
function rebuildObject(object) {
    const
        isNumber = v => typeof v === 'number' && isFinite(v),
        isString = v => typeof v === 'string' || v instanceof String,
        isArray = v => Array.isArray(v),
        isObject = v => v && typeof v === 'object',
        getOrder = v => [isNumber, isString, isArray, isObject].findIndex(fn => fn(v)) + 1 || Infinity;

    return Object.assign(
        ...Object
            .entries(object)
            .sort(({ 1: a }, { 1: b }) => getOrder(a) - getOrder(b))
            .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))
    );
}

console.log(rebuildObject({ id: 3, name: "my object", content: ["a", "b", "c"], description: "my description", anotherArray: [11, 22, 33], contentObject: { id: 56, name: "content object" } }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

So first, objects are not to be ordered like that; which makes the whole operation a bit hard - however, you could sort the object keys. To do that - it's the same as sorting the keys alphabetically or however. Create an array that does the checks in the order you want as a result and use the index

```js
const checks = [
  isNumber,
  isString,
  isArray,
  isPlainSybol,
  isFunction,
  isNull,
  isUndefined,
  isBoolean,
  isDate,
  isRegExp,
  isError,
  isSymbol
];

const myObject = {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "my object",
  "content": ["a", "b", "c"],
  "description": "my description",
  "anotherArray": [11, 22, 33],
  "contentObject": {
    "id": 56,
    "name": "content object"
  }
}

const sortedKeys = Object.keys(myObject).sort((a,b) =>
   checks.findIndex(e => e(myObject[a])) - checks.findIndex(e => e(myObject[b]))
 )

console.log(sortedKeys);
```

```html
<script>
const isString =    (value) => (typeof value === 'string' || value instanceof String);
const isNumber =    (value) => (typeof value === 'number' && isFinite(value));
const isArray =     (value) => (Array.isArray(value));
const isFunction =  (value) => (typeof value === 'function');
const isNull =      (value) => (value === null);
const isUndefined = (value) => (typeof value === 'undefined');
const isBoolean =   (value) => (typeof value === 'boolean');
const isDate =      (value) => (value instanceof Date);
const isRegExp =    (value) => (value && typeof value === 'object' && value.constructor === RegExp);
const isError =     (value) => (value instanceof Error && typeof value.message !== 'undefined');
const isSymbol =    (value) => (typeof value === 'symbol');
const isPlainSybol =(value) => value ? value.constructor === {}.constructor : false;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, objects are not ordered, so you can't sort an object. You *can* sort an array. If you want to sort something you need a value that be compared. In other words, you need to determine if one value is greater, less than, or equal to another. The simplest way to do this is to assign a number to each type that represents the sorting order and the sort based on that. For example, here's a simple (and incomplete) function to map types to numbers:

```
function sortValue(item) {
  let order  = {
    'number': 3,
    'string': 2,
    'object': 0
  }
  if (Array.isArray(item)) return 1
  else if (typeof item in order) return order[typeof item]
  else return -1
}
```

With that you can sort your values (or keys based on values, etc). Of course, this returns an array because arrays unlike objects are ordered:

```js
const myObject = {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "my object",
  "content": ["a", "b", "c"],
  "description": "my description",
  "anotherArray": [11, 22, 33],
  "contentObject": {
    "id": 56,
    "name": "content object"
  }
}

function sortValue(item) {
  let order = {
    'number': 3,
    'string': 2,
    'object': 0
  }
  if (Array.isArray(item)) return 1
  else if (typeof item in order) return order[typeof item]
  else return -1
}

let sortedValues = Object.values(myObject).sort((a, b) => sortValue(b) - sortValue(a))

console.log(sortedValues)
```